# How does cost per seat-mile differ between commercial and private jets?

Tags: commercial-aviation, boeing, efficiency

I was reading an article the other day that mentioned many smaller private jets are more efficient, faster, can climb quicker and land with less space than larger commercial aircraft. Some of the obvious metrics make sense such as shorter landing distances, but the efficiency peaked my curiosity.

I am basically asking what is the cost difference or [cost per seat mile](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Available_seat_miles) difference in say a a Boeing 737 vs a smaller often private jet, say an [Embraer Legacy 600](http://www.embraerexecutivejets.com/en-us/jets/legacy-600/pages/overview.aspx) or similar with its maximum seat capacity setup.

Comment: They've been making 737's since 1966 and efficiency has changed dramatically between the various generations. If you're referring to current generation 737's, you may want to be more specific. Not all 737's are the same size either.

Comment: [AirAsia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AirAsia) has the lowest unit cost of any airline, at US$0.023 per available seat kilometers (ASK) and a passenger break-even load factor of 52%. That's on a fleet of mainly A320-200s.

Comment: Regarding private jets, here's [an article](http://www.telegraph.co.uk/luxury/travel/40807/when-private-jets-are-cheaper-than-budget-airlines.html) about the fare price comparison of a private jet vs easyJet - it looks like only when its on an 'empty leg' that the private jet can be fare price competitive to the customer.

Comment: Are you referring to the maximum seats that would be allowed for the standard "private jet" interior, or how many that jet would fit in an airline-style configuration?

Comment: I was referring to a comfortable but max amount of seats in a private jet ie. no couches/bars etc seen on celebrity planes.

Comment: I guess I should/can specify more. If the same company owned a remotely modern 737 say one that AA is currently flying from the 90s-00s I guess and also owned a Legacy 600 or similar what would be the cost per seat be for each after fuel, staff etc assuming normal conditions

Answer (score 6):

I did some basic math to figure it out in terms of current gas prices.  I got that a private jet is about 6x more expensive.  Keep in mind it is probably more in reality because these jets aren't being used as much as an airliner so the rental price will be higher as well as the fuel.  But like I said, this was just an estimate based on current fuel prices and performance of an airliner vs a private jet, to give you an idea of the cost difference.

[image]

Comment: Good illustration right here.  It's basically like comparing private cars to mass transit.  Mass transit always wins in efficiency, but not always (or even usually) in convenience.

Comment: By the way, that fuel price for the airlines is **WAY** too high, and even private jets usually buy contract fuel and get fuel at cheaper locations than LAX.  Airlines buy is such bulk though that they won't be paying anywhere near that, which gives them an even bigger advantage.

Comment: Thank you. That is what I was asking for. Since I don't know were you got the gal/min cost from, if we changed it to 14 passengers and 600mph what would that be? Not concerned with the accuracy of gas price at the moment this is more for comparison at any gas price.

Comment: @Lnafziger if any thing, airlines should be able to get fuel cheaper due to futures contracts and economies of scale...

Comment: @robokaren That's what I was saying in my comment!  :-)

Comment: @Shaun Well, just for the record, there will normally be a rather large price disparity between fuel prices for the airline versus private jets that will skew the numbers even further towards the airliner.

Comment: I think you're forgetting some other important operational costs.  Like the ramps fees and the pilots salary.

Comment: @JayCarr, this was just to get the basic concept on paper (which I think it does).  Obviously there's a WHOLE lot more to it.

Comment: I understand where you're coming from, but I think that other costs differences between large and small planes would have a very significant impact on the answer. I guess what I'm saying is I feel this is *over* simplified.  Though I would agree that it's a reasonable starting point.

Comment: Nicely done. Q.E.D.